# Pandas Upsample Resample multi-index monthly data to multi-index weekly data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have got 2 years worth of data in a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
In[117]: df
Out[117]: 
                               Str%      Val%      Vol%
State Location Date                                    
NSW   Country  2018-01-01  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-02-01  0.043233  0.050797  0.050907
               2018-03-01  0.045113  0.052550  0.052213
               2018-04-01  0.045113  0.052237  0.052195
               2018-05-01  0.045198  0.050020  0.049767
                             ...       ...       ...
WA    Metro    2019-09-01  0.028958  0.025970  0.027752
               2019-10-01  0.029070  0.025906  0.028062
               2019-11-01  0.029126  0.024388  0.026421
               2019-12-01  0.029126  0.021167  0.023982
               2020-01-01  0.029412  0.027437  0.029197

[300 rows x 3 columns]
```

Data has got three multi-indices `['State', 'Location', 'Date']`. For each **state** and **location** this data is available at monthly level. However, I want to convert it to weekly level and for each state and location. Something as follows,

```
In[119]: df
Out[119]: 
                               Str%      Val%      Vol%
State Location Date                                    
NSW   Country  2018-01-07  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-01-14  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-01-21  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-01-28  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-02-04  0.043233  0.050797  0.050907
```

So far, I have tried using **resample()** function from pandas but it refuses to work with multi-index objects. Moreover, if I remove State and Location from index then my Date index has duplicated entries, which again breaks the **resample()** function. I have also tried using "Grouper" in the groupby() function as follows:

```
df= df.reset_index()
Weekly = pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-SUN', closed='left', label='right')
df.groupby(['State', 'Location', Weekly]).first()
```

This generates following output,

```
Out[121]: 
                               Str%      Val%      Vol%
State Location Date                                    
NSW   Country  2018-01-07  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-02-04  0.043233  0.050797  0.050907
               2018-03-04  0.045113  0.052550  0.052213
               2018-04-08  0.045113  0.052237  0.052195
               2018-05-06  0.045198  0.050020  0.049767
```

As you can see, this only ends up converting the current dates to start of week and doesn't interpolate the missing weeks for each month.

Any help on this?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sees there are monthly data. Solution is changed with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) for chained grouping and resample together:

```
df1 = (df.reset_index(level=[0,1])
         .groupby(['State', 'Location'])
         .resample('W-SUN', closed='left', label='right')
         .first())
```

---

```
print (df1)

                          State Location      Str%      Val%      Vol%
State Location Date                                                   
NSW   Country  2018-01-07   NSW  Country  0.043152  0.052147  0.052867
               2018-01-14   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-01-21   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-01-28   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-02-04   NSW  Country  0.043233  0.050797  0.050907
               2018-02-11   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-02-18   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-02-25   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-03-04   NSW  Country  0.045113  0.052550  0.052213
               2018-03-11   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-03-18   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-03-25   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-04-01   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-04-08   NSW  Country  0.045113  0.052237  0.052195
               2018-04-15   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-04-22   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-04-29   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2018-05-06   NSW  Country  0.045198  0.050020  0.049767
WA    Metro    2019-09-08    WA    Metro  0.028958  0.025970  0.027752
               2019-09-15   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-09-22   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-09-29   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-10-06    WA    Metro  0.029070  0.025906  0.028062
               2019-10-13   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-10-20   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-10-27   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-11-03    WA    Metro  0.029126  0.024388  0.026421
               2019-11-10   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-11-17   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-11-24   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-12-01   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-12-08    WA    Metro  0.029126  0.021167  0.023982
               2019-12-15   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-12-22   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2019-12-29   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
               2020-01-05    WA    Metro  0.029412  0.027437  0.029197
```